# Get the first integers in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, string-formatting

I have a string in a loop and for every loop, it is filled with texts the looks like this:

```
"123 hello everybody 4"
"4567 stuff is fun 67"
"12368 more stuff"
```

I only want to retrieve the first numbers up to the text in the string and I, of course, do not know the length.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you *know* there's a number in the string, you can use this one-liner: `"Hello 123 there! 45".match(/\d+/).shift();` Otherwise, you'll want to test for `null` before doing the `.shift()`.  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/609588/114558)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If the number is at the start of the string:

```
("123 hello everybody 4").replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1'); //=> '123'
```

If it's somewhere in the string:

```
(" hello 123 everybody 4").replace( /(^.+)(\w\d+\w)(.+$)/i,'$2'); //=> '123'
```

And for a number between characters:

```
("hello123everybody 4").replace( /(^.+\D)(\d+)(\D.+$)/i,'$2'); //=> '123'
```

[**addendum**]

A regular expression to match all numbers in a string:

```
"4567 stuff is fun4you 67".match(/^\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g); //=> ["4567", "4", "67"]
```

You can map the resulting array to an array of Numbers:

```
"4567 stuff is fun4you 67"
  .match(/^\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g)
  .map(function (v) {return +v;}); //=> [4567, 4, 67]
```

Including floats:

```
"4567 stuff is fun4you 2.12 67"
  .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g)
  .map(function (v) {return +v;}); //=> [4567, 4, 2.12, 67]
```

If the possibility exists that the string doesn't contain any number, use:

```
( "stuff is fun"
   .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g) || [] )
   .map(function (v) {return +v;}); //=> []
```

So, to retrieve the start or end numbers of the string `4567 stuff is fun4you 2.12 67"`

```
// start number
var startingNumber = ( "4567 stuff is fun4you 2.12 67"
  .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g) || [] )
  .map(function (v) {return +v;}).shift(); //=> 4567

// end number
var endingNumber = ( "4567 stuff is fun4you 2.12 67"
  .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g) || [] )
  .map(function (v) {return +v;}).pop(); //=> 67
```

Comment: These dont work very well. ("hello123").replace( /(^.+\D)(\d+)(\D.+$)/i,'$2') returns "hello124". In fact, none of these work if the number is at the end of the string.

Comment: @user1311069: well, that situation was not included in the answer. It would be constructive if you provided your solution to it. Feel free ;)

Comment: @user1311069: provided a few extra methods, satisfying you needs too.

Comment: These are way too complicated. `"Hello 123 there! 45".match(/\d+/).shift();` works for most needs.  Test for `null` before the `.shift()` if you're not sure if there's a number in the string.

Answer (score 55):

```
var str = "some text and 856 numbers 2";
var match = str.match(/\d+/);
document.writeln(parseInt(match[0], 10));
```

If the strings starts with number (maybe preceded by whitespace), simple `parseInt(str, 10)` is enough.
`parseInt` will skip leading whitespace.

`10` is necessary, because otherwise string like `08` will be converted to `0` (`parseInt` in most implementations consider numbers starting with `0` as octal).

Comment: Given the regular expression `/\d+/` you don't really need `parseInt`, something like `+match.shift()` or `Number(match.shift())` is sufficient. Furthermore, you need to check if there actually is a match. The input string may not contain numbers at all: in that case `match` will be `null`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want an int, just `parseInt(myString, 10)`. (The `10` signifies base 10; otherwise, JavaScript may try to use a different base such as 8 or 16.)

Answer (score 5):

This **`replace`** method with **a simple regular expression** (`[^\d].*`):

```
'123 your 1st string'.replace( /[^\d].*/, '' );
// output: "123"
```

remove **everything without the first digits**.

Answer (score 3):

Use Regular Expressions:

```
var re = new RegExp(/^\d+/); //starts with digit, one or more
var m = re.exec("4567 stuff is fun 67");
alert(m[0]); //4567

m = re.exec("stuff is fun 67");
alert(m); // null
```