# Regex matching a string pattern and number ( url format )

Tags: javascript, regex, google-forms

I have a string that follows this url pattern as

```
https://www.examples.org/activity-group/8712/activity/202803
// note :  the end ending of the url can be different
https://www.examples.org/activity-group/8712/activity/202803‌​?ref=bla
https://www.examples.org/activity-group/8712/activity/202803‌​/something
```

I'm trying to write a regex that matches

```
https://www.examples.org/activity-group/{number}/activity/{number}*
```

Where **{number}** is an integer of length 1 to 10.

**How to define a regex that checks the string pattern and checks if the number is at the right position in the string ?**

Background: in Google form, in order validate an answer , I want to enforce people to enter an url in this format.  Hence the use of this regular expression.

For Urls not matching that format, the regex should return false.  For example : https://www.notthesite.org/group/8712/activity/astring

I went through several examples, but they match only if the number is present in the string.

Examples sources :

- [How to find a number in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)
- [Get the first Int(s) in a string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609574/get-the-first-ints-in-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Show your best attempt.

Comment: sorry, I cannot understand why
`https://www\.examples\.org/activity-group/\d{1,10}/activity/\d{1,10}$` does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^https:\/\/www\.examples\.org\/activity-group\/[0-9]{1,10}\/activity\/[0-9]{1,10}(\/[a-z]+)*((\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\&[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*$`

- `^` - start of string
- `\` - escape character
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `{1,10}` - between one and ten of the previous items
- `(\/[a-z]+)*` - Allow additional URL segments
- `((\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\&[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*` - Allow query parameters with first parameter using a `?` and all others using `&`
- `$` - end of string

This is assuming the URL segment and query parameter keys are lowercase letters only. The query parameter values can be lowercase letters, uppercase letters, or digits.

Comment: Thanks Alec, I forgot to say something , the ending of the url can be different `https://www.examples.org/activity-group/8712/activity/202803?ref=bla` or `https://www.examples.org/activity-group/8712/activity/202803/something` .  How to match ?

Comment: @RaymondChenon Edited

Comment: Thanks again. I tried [here][https://regex101.com/r/QINDkA/1/] , the one with `activity/202803‌​?ref=bla` matches . But the other don't :  `activity/202803‌​` and  `activity/202803‌​/something` .

Comment: @RaymondChenon I missed the last `*`, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
https?:\/\/(?:[^/]+\/){2}(\d+)\/[^/]+\/(\d+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kCEYII/2).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
https?:\/\/     # http:// or https://
(?:[^/]+\/){2}  # not "/", followed by "/", twice
(\d+)           # 1+ digits
\/[^/]+\/       # same pattern as above
(\d+)           # the other number
```

You'll need to use group `1` and `2`, respectively.

---

If this is too permissive, use

```
https:\/\/[^/]+\/activity-group\/(\d+)\/activity\/(\d+)
```

Which reads

```
https:\/\/[^/]+     # https:// + some domain name
\/activity-group\/  # /activity-group/
(\d+)               # first number
\/activity\/        # /activity/
(\d+)               # second number
```

See another [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kCEYII/2).

Comment: You solution is a gem of wisdom. I thought it was too permissive, I hacked a bit. My final solution is `https:\/\/www\.examples\.org\/activity-group\/(\d+)\/activity\/(\d+)`

Comment: @RaymondChenon: Glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like:

```
(http[s]?:\/\/)?www.examples.org\/activity-group\/(\d{1,10})\/activity\/(\d{1,10})([\S]+?)$
```

Where:

- `(http[s]?:\/\/)?` matches any *http://* or *https://* part.
- `www.examples.org` is your domain name.
- `(\d{1,10})` will match the first integer with max len of 10(after *activity-group*).
- Second `(\d{1,10})` will match the second integer after *activity*.
- And finally `([\S]+?)$` will match any optional data after the second number until a new line is found, assuming that you use multiline flag with `\m`.

Check it at http://regexr.com/3h448

Hope it helps!