# Call a specific function if the first occurrences of the array items is number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of items like this:

```
const items = ['98 ab','dv 67','96 bh',' 95 df'];
```

What I am trying is that: to loop over to these items and call a specific functions if the first occurances of the items starts with a number. For example:
if items starts with (98) and then call `functionA` and if items starts with (dv) then call `functionB`.

```
const result = items.map(el=>
 if(el==='items that starts with number') {
  functionA;
  } else {
   functionB
  })
```

So according to the items array, I should call the functionA three times as there three values that starts with a number in it.

Any ideas how I can achieve it.I need to use Javascript for this. thanks is advance.

Comment: `/^\d/.test(thing)` returns true when `thing` is a string starting with a digit.

Comment: what is with strings with space before digits? or the rest of other strings?

Comment: They are rest of other strings doesn't matter. But the item need to be filtered is the one starts with number/digits.

Comment: btw, you are using `map`. what do you like to filter?

Comment: You could parse the string and check if the result is a number or not `items.map(el => isNaN(parseInt(el, 10)) ? functionB(el) : functionA(el))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to check if each element in the array starts with a number. If it does, you call functionA; otherwise, you call functionB.

```
const items = ['98 ab', 'dv 67', '96 bh', '95 df'];

function functionA(item) {
  console.log('Called functionA with item:', item);
}

function functionB(item) {
  console.log('Called functionB with item:', item);
}

const result = items.map(el => {
  if (/^\d/.test(el)) {
    return functionA(el);
  } else {
    return functionB(el);
  }
});
```

The ^\d checks if the string starts with a digit.

I just create a small example, but since you are not transforming the array into a new array, a simple forEach could be more appropriate if you don't need the result array for other purposes.

Here's how you can modify the example to use forEach:

```
const items = ['98 ab', 'dv 67', '96 bh', '95 df'];

function functionA(item) {
  console.log('Called functionA with item:', item);
}

function functionB(item) {
  console.log('Called functionB with item:', item);
}

items.forEach(el => {
  if (/^\d/.test(el)) {
    functionA(el);
  } else {
    functionB(el);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the map here? Just, If I would like to use map instead of forEach?

Comment: forEach would be more appropriate than map. The map method is typically used for creating a new array by transforming each element of the original array.  forEach is used for executing a function on each element of the array without creating a new array.
But is just my opinion, I edited my answer adding the foreach example too... so you can chose.

Answer (score 0):

If you [extract the number from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/how-can-i-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-javascript), you can use a simple object to map the found number to a function of your liking.

If you only want to search for numbers at the beginning of the string, use the `replace` solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609574/get-the-first-integers-in-a-string-with-javascript):

```
let n = item.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1');
```

---

```js
const functionMap = {
  98:         (n) => console.log('Function #1;', n),
  67:         (n) => console.log('Function #2;', n),
  "default":  (n) => console.log('Not Found', n)
};

const items = ['98 ab','dv 67','96 bh',' 95 df'];

items.forEach(item => {
//  let n = item.match(/\d+/)[0];                 // Everywhere
    let n = item.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1');   // Start only

    let k = (n in functionMap) ? n : 'default';
    functionMap[k](n);
});
```

Which outputs:

```
Function #1; 98
Function #2; 67
Not Found 96
Not Found 95
```

Since I've only provided a number in `functionMap` for `98` and `67`.

Answer (score 0):

You could trim the string and check with a regular expression.

```js
const
    fnA = (v) => console.log('fnA:', v),
    fnB = (v) => console.log('fnB:', v),
    items = ['98 ab','dv 67','96 bh',' 95 df'];

items.forEach(el => {
   if (/^\d/.test(el.trim())) fnA(el);
   else if (/^[a-z]/i.test(el.trim())) fnB(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it will help. But maybe you can try something like this.

```js
const items = ['98 ab','dv 67','96 bh',' 95 df'];

items.forEach(item=> {
    
    const firstChar= [...item.trim()][0]; // 9,d,9,9
    
    isNaN(firstChar)? B():A(); 
    
})

function A(){
    console.log('This is function A. Its a Number')
}

function B(){
    console.log('This is function B. Its a String')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
items.forEach(el=>{
 const firstTwoChars=el.slice(0,2);
 if(typeof parseInt(firstTwoChars) === 'number') {
  functionA();
  } else {
   functionB();
  }
});
```